# Write into Hadoop File System in parallel

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm quite new with Hadoop, and I have a issue...

I have a output file (the result of a task) and I would like to modify it. As it can be a **very** big file, i want to do this operation in parralel.

*Note : I don't want to simply append data, i want to modify structurally (even the size) so I have to read it completely and write it back*

Read the file isn't a problem, i give to each worker a part of the file, they simply have to read it and make the changes they want.

But for writing the new file back to hdfs it seems more tricky.

**My question is:** how can I Create a big file into the hdfs and make my workers write into it simultaneously (i know the size of each part so two workers will never attempt to write at the same position).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the job is to read the input file and write select content from the input files to a output location in parallel, this is a mapper only job.

1. Create a Mapper class to read the file and perform your operations on
   the file.

set the number for mappers in your driver class.

```
  job.setNumMapTasks(n); n-number of mappers
```